# Variable not echo'ing out properly in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm following the [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org) to get started (for the 4000th time) with Ruby on Rails. I'm pretty much racing through the first couple of chapters, as I have already read and typed these quite a lot of times but I just ran into a minor problem which I cannot seem to solve.

In one of the chapters, it is suggested that we create a helper function to make the displaying of page titles more dynamic.

The helper looks like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  
  #return title on per page basis
  def title
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if @title.nil?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
    end
  end
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = "Home"
  end
  # more pages
end
```

And finally, my application layout file contains the following line:

```
  <title><%= @title %></title>
```

The books says that it should now "echo" (is this PHP lingo? Tee-hee) the following title:

`Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home` for the homepage. However, it only echoes 'Home' as the page title.

Am I overlooking something here? I don't think I typed any errors or anything; everything looks fairly logical to me, however it won't work.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling @title in your view refers to the variable, not the method. As the variable @title is equal to "Home", this is what you get. To call the method, you should try something like :

```
<title><%= title %></title>
```

Comment: Ohh, duh. Silly me, I didn't see they removed the @ in the book. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've mis-copied from the book. (Good thing the problem you're having is in the free sample chapter. :)

What the book *actually* has is:

> ```
> <title><%= title %></title>
> ```

What you have is:

> ```
> <title><%= @title %></title>
> ```

With the `@`, that directly looks up the variable. Without the `@`, it calls the method `title()`. (I wish they had put `()` after the function call, but that *is* idiomatic Ruby. I just dislike the Ruby idiom.)

Comment: Duh. Silly me, I did indeed miss that little @ being gone there. Oh well, free rep for everyone, haha. Thanks a lot for helping me out! And thanks for explaining that title without the @ is a method call; I never would've gotten that on my own.